# AngularUI-Bootstrap Typeahead: Search hint inside the textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead

We are trying to implement autocomplete using AngularUI-Bootstrap `Typeahead` feature. An additional feature is to have autocomplete with a hint inside the textbox itself. Like a Google search, when one starts typing the search text, the autocomplete results are shown below the textbox, but also the textbox shows the hint.[image]

I tried implementing this using a variable inside `placeholder` property, but didn't work. What exactly is this behavior called and are there any pointers I can refer to- to achieve this? Tried Googling around but in vain, couldn't get any useful resource to proceed. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well placeholder will not work as it's visible only when input is empty, what you need is a layer under the input that will display the same value as it is done for google autocomplete

If you open dev tools you will see there are 2 inputs, one over another

[image]